# Background is not moving, cannot figure it out

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the white section in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsKUg.jpg) move down to where the top of the white section is just above where the red and white separate and then want the logo the go just slightly over the white section.  I've been working on it for 2 days and get nothing to work, help.

```
<div id="header">
  <span id="header_icon"></span>
  <div id="header_content">
    <div id="site_title">                        
      <a href="index.html" target="_parent">
        <img src="images/sltlogobolt.png" alt="LOGO" height=400 width=350>
      </a>
    </div>
    <p></p>       
  </div>
</div> <!-- end of header -->

<div id="main_content_top"></div>
<div id="main_content_middle">
   <span id="main_content_top"></span>
   <span id="main_content_bottom"></span>
</div>

#header_content img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#main_content_top {
  width: 984px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(images/content_top.png) no-repeat;
}

#main_content_bottom {
  width: 984px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(images/content_bottom.png) no-repeat
}

#main_content_middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  padding: 10px 42px;
  background: url(images/content_middle.png) repeat-y
}
```

Comment: i really don't understand your description, can you please rephrase it perhaps? :)

Comment: your question really is not clear.  Can you use MSPaint or something to mock up an image of what exactly it is you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#main_content_top {
width: 984px;
height: 30px;
margin-top:50px;
background: url(images/content_top.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Try this.